# Mongoid geonear query with max distance not working properly

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, geospatial

I am confused about the geonear query with mongoid. It seems that I am missing something and when I m trying to query for points near the given coordinates with max distance 200 meters form my controller with the following:

```
     Coord.geo_near([params[:lon].to_i,    params[:lat].to_i]).max_distance(200)
```

I get all the points that are available in the collection in the same order for every set of coords that i provide.

My model:

```
     class Coord
     include Mongoid::Document
     include Mongoid::Geospatial

     field :Message, :type => String

     field :location, type: Point, spatial: true
     end
```

I have created the 2dsphere index from mongo console:

```
     db.coords.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } )
```

I have also tried instead of 200 meters to provide 0.2/111.2 in the case that the max_distance works with degrees but in this case I m not getting any results.

Answer (score -1):

Use Earth radius

To search in 10km radius:

`Coord.geo_near([params[:lon].to_f, params[:lat].to_f]).max_distance(10.fdiv(6_371))`